# Moving a install of bolt.cm

Tags: bolt-cms

I am trying to move my location on disk of a Bolt.cm install. Config.yml doesnt have any details of location.

When I rename the directory I receive  app config issues as well as this :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Bolt\Exception\LowLevelDatabaseException

Thrown from within Bolt. Seems like I need to update a config file but I don't see one with the path do web root or path to database stored.

Does such a file exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flush the cache.

This can be done from the command line by:

```
php app/nut cache:clear
```

Or inside `app/cache/` you will find the file `config_cache.php` that can be safely deleted.

Comment: Thank you! that was surprising easy, thanks for an excellent product @gawain